# How to print multiple reports using ASP.NET GridView, RDLC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, reportviewer, rdlc

I want to print reports based on GridView checkbox. If 3 rows have been chosen, there should be 3 reports. My code is like this...

```
protected void btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow gvr in grdRV.Rows)
                {
                    RadioButton rbID = (RadioButton)gvr.FindControl("rbID") as RadioButton;

                    if (rbID != null && rbID.Checked)
                    {
                        string sID = grdRV.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim();

                        if (rbl_Print.SelectedValue == "0")
                        {
                            SMTP(sID);
                        }
                        else if (rbl_Print.SelectedValue == "1")
                        {
                            Material(sID);
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Session["error"] = ex.Message;
                Response.Redirect("MessageBoard.aspx");
            }
        }
    }

private void Material(string sID)
    {            

        string querystring = "../pmis/Reports/RptRFQMatV.aspx?RFQNo=" + lblRFQNo.Text.ToString() + "&ID=" + sID;

        Random r = new Random();            
        string Script = "";
        Script += "<script language=JavaScript id='PopupWindow'>";
        Script += "confirmWin = window.open(' " + querystring + "','" + r.Next() + "','scrollbars=yes,resizable=1, width=960,height=500,left=50,top=130,status');";
        Script += "confirmWin.Setfocus()</script>";

        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "PopupScript", "PopupWindow");
        if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("PopupWindow"))
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(string), "PopupWindow", Script);
    }
```

...but currently this code can print report the last row only.

Comment: what happens when you set a breakpoint in this code? Why does it not catch the 3 that you expect?

Comment: @p.campbell: let say I checked 3 rows, I will have 3 ID. for e.g: A0031, A0027, A0051. So firstly A0031 go to Material block, after finish A0027, and then A0051. So Report come out for A0051 only. Other two IDs not come out. may be overwrite or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this and it does open the three windows, you'll have to tweak it a bit by passing a list of selected IDs to Material, so that you call Material just once. Inside material in your string manipulation, after the following line,

```
Script += "<script language=JavaScript id='PopupWindow'>";
```

add a for loop that goes though the selected IDs and adds a window.open. So, the following lines should be in the for/foreach loop

```
string querystring = "../pmis/Reports/RptRFQMatV.aspx?RFQNo=" + lblRFQNo.Text.ToString() + "&ID=" + sID;


Script += "confirmWin = window.open(' " + querystring + "','" + r.Next() + "','scrollbars=yes,resizable=1, width=960,height=500,left=50,top=130,status');";
```

and then the following lines follow and are outside the for loop.

```
Script += "confirmWin.Setfocus()</script>";

        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "PopupScript", "PopupWindow");
        if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("PopupWindow"))
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(string), "PopupWindow", Script);
```

This is my example and works. Also, would be better if you use StringBuilder instead of string +=

```
        string Script = "";
        Script += "<script language=JavaScript id='PopupWindow'>";
        Script += "window.open('www.google.com.au', '1','scrollbars=yes,resizable=1, width=960,height=500,left=50,top=130,status');";
        Script += "window.open('www.yahoo.com','2','scrollbars=yes,resizable=1, width=960,height=500,left=50,top=130,status');";
        Script += "window.open('www.stackoverflow.com','3', 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=1, width=960,height=500,left=50,top=130,status');";
        Script += "</script>";

        if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("PopupWindow"))
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(string), "PopupWindow", Script);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @CMMaung: My example is using static data as it is a proof of concept. If you read my instructions above my example, I think you should be ok. And I don't understand how does it matter if the windows are opened when the whole loop is finished as this code executes server side and will always open the windows in one go, when the response finally reaches the client side. Maybe I'm not understanding your requirements completely.